# Failed to load viewstate when page contains viewstate variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error when I don't use or do processing on pages which contain viewstate for couple minutes and reload the page:

**`Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.`**

I have got the solution by setting page setting **enableviewstate= false**

but after applying this the viewstate variable doesnot work on this page.

Comment: can u show some code. what u want to do actually....

Comment: Its not an issue on single page its on every page which have viewstate

Comment: enableviewstate= false does exactly what it says on the tin, it disables viewstate (with the exception of certain controlstate which can't be switched off) across the entire page. It cannot be overridden for individual objects or controls. No objects would be able to be saved to viewstate with this set to false, and most persisted control state will be lost. The error message itself is fairly self-explanatory and Kaerber has given a good description of both the likely problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this issue occurred because I was creating control which affecting the control position value as it was not able to close render the tag of that control. by correcting the control tag it was corrected

Answer (score 2):

The cause could be that you dynamically add controls in Page_Load. I.e. you add some grid in Page_Load, and its view state is saved into page, but then, when page is posted back, and ViewState is parsed, the engine cannot find respective controls for a parsed ViewState.

That's becase Load event (which is handled by Page_Load) is fired **after** page is fully loaded, i.e. children created, view state parsed and applied, but before client events like on click fired and the page is rendered.

Move addition of dynamic controls to Page_Init, and make sure they are exactly the same each time they are created, i.e. both on first page init and on page init after postback.

A helpful link [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)